# Total mean curvature of an immersed torus.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, knot-theory

How to prove that the total mean curvature of an immersed torus of $R^3$ such that has nontrivial self-intersection must $> 8 \pi$? The definition of total mean curvature is the integral of $H^2$ over the immersed manifold, where H is the mean curvature.
I don't have any idea about it.

Comment: Average curvature = mean curvature?

Comment: Ahhhhh, yes, you are right, I made a mistake.

Comment: The weak version ($\ge 8 \pi$) of this is inequality (23) in Topping's 1998 paper "Mean Curvature Flow and Geometric Inequalities". I don't have time to read it now, nor do I know if it's the easiest proof of this particular result; but have a look.

Comment: @Anthony Carapetis , thanks a lot!

Comment: Check Theorem 6 of 
A New Conformal Invariant and Its Applications to the Willmore Conjecture and the First Eigenvalue of Compact Surfaces. Peter
Li and Shing-Tung Yau

Comment: http://www.doctoryau.com/papers/NewConformalInvariant.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Li and Yau (1982): If  is not embedded, then $\mathcal{W(\Sigma)}\geq{8\pi}$.

Fix $v\in\mathbb{R}^4$ and consider the vector field $x=v^\perp(x)$, given by tangential
projection on $T_x\mathbb{S}^3$.

It is a conformal killing vector field in $\mathbb{S}^3$ and generates
a flow $\phi_t$ of centered dilations. By conformal invariance of Willmore energy,

$$\mathcal{W(\Sigma)}=\mathcal{W(\phi_t(\Sigma))}=\int_{\phi_t(\Sigma)}(1+H^2_{\phi_t(\Sigma)})d\phi_t(\Sigma)\geq\hbox{area}(\phi_t(\Sigma))$$

If we choose $v\in\Sigma$ and let $t\longrightarrow\infty$, we have
$\mathcal{W(\Sigma)}\geq{4}\pi$. In case $F:\Sigma\longrightarrow{\mathbb{S}^3}$ is immersion and $p\in\Sigma$ satises that #$F^{-1}(p)=k$, then $\mathcal{W(\Sigma)}\geq{4\pi}$k.

Comment: Oh great. I don't quite understand your last paragraph, could you expand a little bit? I don't understand why when t goes to infinity the Willmore energy will be bigger than $4pi$. And by last sentence do you mean that if we have one point that has a fiber have k points then the Willmore energy will more than $4pi k$? Why so? I can't see directly from the formula above.

Comment: All the details are in 
 
doctoryau.com/papers/NewConformalInvariant.pdf

Answer (score 0):

For every smooth immersed torus $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$

$$\int_MH^2dA≥ 2π^2$$.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Willmore_conjecture

Comment: Willmore conjecture won't apply to this， as pi is smaller than 4... There must be something to do with the self intersection.